# How to manage session in android application for 30 minutes

Tags: android

I have an application that i want to set session to application means when i logged in to app and not used for 30 minutes like app running in background or screen off then i want to directly show login screen.is there any solution.?

Answer (score 0):

**App running in background**
First thing you need to start a thread from your application to check the currently running application, find out the application on top use the following code to do this

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
String currentRunningActivityPackageName = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

This will return the current running application package, compare it with your application package name. If the application is not matching start a timer, if the timer cross 30 minutes,you can log out of your application, if in mean time your application comes in foreground stop the timer.
**Screen off** 
For screen of you can register a broadcast

```
BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    //When Event is published, onReceive method is called
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "MyReceiver");

            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
                Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "Screen ON");
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
                Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "Screen OFF");
            }

    }
};

 @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
   registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
 }
```

So according to the intent received you can toggle the same timer.

Answer (score 0):

For managing the session you you have to store the data some where like [SharedPrefrence](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). After that youcan use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) as given below in your First Activity.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   //Clear the Shared prefrence here 
      //here you can start your Login Activity
  }
}, 1000);// Change the time according to need
```

Comment: but i have around 20 activities so how i can manage? and where exactly i store data in sharedpreferences?

Comment: Just do this in your first activity,Number of activity is not a problem. Try to study sharedpref. I gave you the link above. Like sharedpref you can use SQLLite,Internal storage etc which is comfortable for you. The link is here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html